# plotting an Integration output

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

How to solve this integral by Mathematica even by numerical methods (plotting the solution)

```
Integrate[(Cos[x] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2*a*Cos[x])^1.5, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

It consumes huge time on Mathematica 9 home edition and no output.

I just want the Taylor expansion in the vicinity of a=0

Comment: Why integral over `[0,1]` when you have `[0, 2 Pi]` in the picture ?

Comment: Yes, it was an error. I edited the post to be [0, 2 Pi]. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
expr =  Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[(Cos[x] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2*a*Cos[x])^(3/2), {x, 0, 1}]]
```

gives:

```
(-(-1 + a) Sqrt[1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[1]] ((-1 + a) EllipticE[1/
      2, -((4 a)/(-1 + a)^2)] + (1 + a) EllipticF[1/
      2, -((4 a)/(-1 + a)^2)]) - 
 2 a Abs[-1 + a] Sin[1])/(a (-1 + a^2) Abs[-1 + a] Sqrt[
 1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[1]])
```

Note: I replaced `1.5` by the radical `3/2`. If you want numerical value use `NIntegrate`

As suggested by b.gatessuck (also belisarius' answer), taking the indefinite integral makes this faster:

```
expr = Integrate[(Cos[x] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2*a*Cos[x])^(3/2), x]
```

Gives:

```
 (-(-1 + a)^2 Sqrt[(1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[x])/(-1 + a)^2]
       EllipticE[x/2, -((4 a)/(-1 + a)^2)] - (-1 + a^2) Sqrt[(
      1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[x])/(-1 + a)^2]
       EllipticF[x/2, -((4 a)/(-1 + a)^2)] - 
     2 a Sin[x])/(a (-1 + a^2) Sqrt[1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[x]])
```

You can then `Plot` this like any other function:

```
Plot[(expr/.x -> 1) - ( expr /. x -> 0 ), {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR from 0 to `2 Pi`

```
Plot[(expr/.x -> 2 Pi) - ( expr /. x -> 0 ), {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Try the indefinite integral first, then take the limits and see if it's faster.

Comment: @b.gatessucks. Thanks, that definitely makes it instantaneous.

Comment: And that was my answer :)

Comment: @belisarius Beat you by a whole 35 seconds.

Comment: @b.gatessucks We should take some relativistic effects in account. Here `G` is fluctuating madly right now

Comment: @belisarius Good enough, you win.

Answer (score 4):

This will compute the Taylor expansion:

Define the integrand.

```
g[θ_, a_] := (Cos[θ] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2 a Cos[θ])^(3/2)
```

Integrate a series expansion.

```
gi[a_, n_] := Integrate[Series[g[θ, a], {a, 0, n}] // Normal, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

Find a sequence function that fits a sufficiently long series expansion.

```
gs[a_, n_] = FindSequenceFunction[List @@ Expand@gi[a, 15]][n] // FullSimplify

(* (4 (a^2)^n Gamma[1/2 + n]^2)/(a Gamma[n] Gamma[1 + n]) *)
```

Summing this over $n = 1, 2, ...$ gives you the required series expansion.

Comment: Nice one :) I tried `FindSequenceFunction[]` with 12 terms and then abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is instantaneous:

```
p = Integrate[(Cos[x] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2*a*Cos[x])^(3/2), x, 
    Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals], GenerateConditions -> True];
Plot[(p /. x -> 1) - (p /. x -> 0), {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In case you made a mistake and the upper integration limit was `2 Pi`:

```
Plot[(p /. x -> 2 Pi) - (p /. x -> 0), {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

As for the series expansion:

```
s = Normal@Series[(p /. x -> 2 Pi) - (p /. x -> 0), {a, 0, 10}]
```

> a π + (9 a^3 π)/8 + (75 a^5 π)/64 + (1225 a^7 π)/1024 + (19845 a^9 π)/16384

The numerators are the [Denominators of the column sums of the BG2 matrix](http://oeis.org/search?q=9,%2075,%201225,%2019845,%20160083&language=english&go=Search)

The denominators follows some power of `2` rule, but not trivial:

```
s = Series[(p /. x -> 2 Pi) - (p /. x -> 0), {a, 0, 100}];
lf = Denominator /@ List @@ Normal@s;
ListLogPlot@lf
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps the following may help you if you need to find a closed expression:

```
s = Series[(p /. x -> 2 Pi) - (p /. x -> 0), {a, 0, 1000}];
lf = Differences[Last /@ Flatten /@ FactorInteger /@ Denominator /@ List @@ Normal@s];
ListLinePlot@lf
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just `p = Integrate[(Cos[x] - a)/(1 + a^2 - 2*a*Cos[x])^(3/2), x]` will do, other options seem to be redundant in this case.

Comment: @Blackbird GenerateConditions is a safeguard against special values, so I'd rather prefer to let it be. The Reals assumption is just a clichè